# Product of 2 Matrix Exponential or PH Random variables, $Z = X\cdot Y$

Tags: probability, products, matrix-exponential

Given two iid Matrix Exponential or PH distributed random variables, $X$ and $Y$, how can I find the PDF of the random variable $Z=X \cdot Y$?

Answer (score 0):

By independence and equal distribution
$$F_{X\cdot Y}(u)=\int F_X(u/x)f_X(x)dx,$$
and the result follows by differentiation w.r.t. $u$. I don't believe the Markov structure underlying Phase-type distributions can make it more explicit.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to know *how* to do these using a Matrix or PH distribution.